# How to add a row when a certain value in a cell is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data:

[image: Data list]

I have data validation set up for entering Y or N within the "more issues Column".

I need a row to be inserted under that when Y is selected, without having to run a macro.

I am running Excel 2016.

Comment: Look in to the [`Worksheet Change Event`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change)

Comment: that does not show to to automatically set it to change...

Comment: No, but it can trigger the VBA that will effect the changes

Comment: Hiya. Is there any VBA that you wrote that you could add here?

Comment: Andrew, I update the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this macro: place in the worksheet object.
*Updated

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'If the cell already has a capital "Y" and you 
    'double click the cell it will insert a row.
    'And typing a "Y" into any other column will not error 

    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = "Y" Then
            Target.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: That is pretty much how I would of done it GMalc but don't you think you would also need the reversal to be there as well?

Comment: GMalc, thank you tons! this worked great. I have a question though. Can we set up this VBA to just read one particular cell to insert another row.? if I type anything in the cell next to it etc it says "run time error 91 " and I have to end the variable. I guess if there is a way that it just reads the column () and does not bug out if you type outside that it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some working code to get you started. Just place the code in the sheet you are using by right clicking the sheet tab and selecting `view code`.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Range, sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
If Not Application.Intersect(Range("B2:B8"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    Set r = Target
    If r = "Y" Then r.Offset(1, 0) = "populated cell"
End If
End Sub
```

The animated gif (click to see detail) show entering N or Y and having the cell below only Y's populated. Ask if you have questions about how this works.

[image]

Comment: I like your gif. Seems like a good way to demonstrate something without having to write out a complicated description.